# Purpose of rescan_spent command

Tags: monerod-commands

What is the purpose of the `rescan_spent` command? Once I spend an output, why would I need to scan my spent outputs to search for it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, the wallet's idea of what outputs are spent and what outputs are not get out of sync with the blockchain. This can happen if you exit the wallet without saving after sending a tx, or if it crashes.

`rescan_spent` will look for the key images on the blockchain to make sure it's up to date.

Since this involves sending your key images to the daemon, it needs a trust daemon, since otherwise this is a privacy breach. So if you are using a remote daemon, you will only be able to use that command if you started moneor-wallet-cli with the `--trusted-daemon` option (by default, local daemons are trusted).